# Newbie: Help with Vertical Spacing on Footer Widget

Tags: widgets, footer

I'm a WP newbie here and trying to get a sense of how everything's working around WP and CSS in particular. I'm currently designing my Footer layout that has 4 Widget areas arranged horizontally. The widgets I choose are the Posts Categories, Pages, Menus, and Woocommerce Product Categories, which give me a list of all menus and pages of my site.

For some reason, the list from Woocommerce Product Categories is not vertically aligned with those from other widgets. The spacing seems off and each row looks slightly below where it should be positioned (please see attached image).

Anybody could help point out where I go wrong? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a website link here so I can help you.

Comment: sure. it's http://tfdesign.co.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change CSS as below.

```
.widget.woocommerce.widget_product_categories ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Anthony Thank you for this. please mark (tick) as green mark of my answer as well as click on up arrow for "This answer is useful" so it can help for someone which is finding like this.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot for your help. Hope this will be useful for others!